# How do you walk an Element tree parsed using Python's elmenttree module?

Tags: python, elementtree, nmap

So I spent about half the day yesterday playing around in the interactive python command line trying to figure out how to navigate this ElementTree, and it's confusing the crap out of me. As per this site https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree I loaded the tree by doing

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nmaptest.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

And then I was going through the examples, and trying to figure out how to access and iterate through each element. Just as soon as I think I'm starting to get how it's pieced together, I can't get it to do what I want it to.

Ultimately I'd like to parse it and dump the pertinent data into a database for later comparison (or maybe write a script that will simply compare two xml docs, but that's looking beyond my abilities currently.)

I've tried things like the following

```
for host in root.iter('host'):
    print host.attrib['name']
    for address in host.iter('address'):
            print address.attrib['addr']
            for port in host.iter('port'):
                    print port.attrib['portid']
```

In an attempt to print out the hostname, IP address, and ports open for each... It doesn't quite work, it's almost like hostname and address are in completely different worlds, though I can't see why that would be. I also found out that you can access the address by simply doing

```
print host[1].attrib['addr']
```

But I can't find any kind of consistency in when things are indexed by an integer, such as above (since host[3] doesn't appear to be hostname like you'd think it would be, logically, and host[2] seems to be hostnames, but has no .attrib or anything), when they're an attribute, and when they're also a dictionary key. It seems like sometimes when I THINK I've found what I'm looking for, instead of seeing something like

```
for host in root.iter('host'):
    print host[1].attrib

{'addrtype': 'ipv4', 'addr': '10.1.102.255'}
```

I'll do a .attrib on something and see empty brackets {} like when I do

```
for host in root.iter('host'):
    print host[2].attrib
```

So I'm not understanding how it parses the document at all... I don't suppose anyone can help clear it up or point me to some documentation that might help me?

Here's a sample entry from the XML output...

```
<host starttime="1408488852" endtime="1408499159"><status state="up" reason="user-set" reason_ttl="0"/>
  <address addr="X.X.X.X" addrtype="ipv4"/>
  <hostnames>
      <hostname name="computername.domainname.com" type="PTR"/>
  </hostnames>
  <ports>
    <extraports state="filtered" count="986">
      <extrareasons reason="no-responses" count="986"/>
    </extraports>
    <port protocol="tcp" portid="X"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="127"/>    <service name="X" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
    <port protocol="tcp" portid="X"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="127"/>    <service name="X" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
    <port protocol="tcp" portid="X"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="127"/>    <service name="X" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
  </ports>
  <times srtt="332" rttvar="164" to="100000"/>
</host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code,

```
for host in root.iter('host'):
    print host.attrib['name']
```

you are trying to access the `name` attribute of the `host` element. But it is the `hostname` element that has that attribute.

Here is one way to get the data that you wanted to extract (assuming that there is one or more `host` elements as children of a common root element in nmaptest.xml):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nmaptest.xml')

hosts = tree.findall(".//host")

for host in hosts:
    for elem in host.iter():
        if elem.tag == "hostname":
            print elem.attrib['name']
        if elem.tag == "address":
            print elem.attrib['addr']
        if elem.tag == "port":
            print elem.attrib['portid']
```

Output:

```
X.X.X.X
computername.domainname.com
X
X
X
```

Comment: This definitely works, and helps with that problem, but I'd still like to understand how it's put together so that I can do other things on my own. Even with your working example above, since I was using the -Pn switch, I'd like to be able to clean out all the entries with `<ports><extraports count="1000" state="filtered">` but I don't know how to refer to anything. Would that "1000" be host.elem.attrib['count'] or what?

Comment: For example, if I do 
`for host in root.iter('host'):
    for elem in host.iter():
            if elem.tag == "extraports":
                    if elem.attrib['count'] == "1000":
                        print elem.attrib['count']`
Then it prints only those elements with a count of 1000, but if I change the print line to root.remove(host), then I rerun the above command, they're all still there... nothing removed... What gives?

Comment: I may be able to help, but I think that you should ask a new question. Comments are not well suited to code longer than one line. And now you are asking about something new (removing elements) that wasn't part of the original question.